# Recode Missing Data from Character Field

Tags: r

Note: The title may be misleading. If you understand my problem and think of something more descriptive - please change it.

I've got a strange situation where the responses from a survey are all character, rather than numeric. It seems that R, really doesn't like this. Let's say I asked a question:

```
Q. In what area do you work? 
East
West
Central
North
South
None of the above
```

But respondents were only from the east, west and central.

```
dat <- rep(c("East", "West", "Central"),100)
```

Now, for presentation purposes, it's important that I include North, south and None of the above, even if they are none. However, factoring those elements in is challenging.

Let's try:

```
fac1 <- factor(dat, labels=c("East","West","Central","North","South","None of the above"))

Error in factor(dat, labels = c("East", "West", "Central", "North", "South",  : 
  invalid labels; length 6 should be 1 or 3
```

Basically, what i'd like to do is factor this data with the missing values. So that when I type something like summary(fac1) it shows them having 0 responses in that category.

There has to be an easier way to do this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there. You need to use the `levels` argument:

```
fac1 <- factor(dat, levels=c("East","West","Central","North","South","None of the above"))
str(fac1)
 Factor w/ 6 levels "East","West",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
```

---

The difference between `levels` and `labels` is this:

- `levels` defines the factor levels in your data
- `labels` allows you to rename the factor levels in one go.

For example:

```
fac2 <- factor(
  dat, 
  levels=c("East","West","Central","North","South","None of the above"),
  labels=c("E", "W", "C", "N", "S", "Other")
)
str(fac2)
Factor w/ 6 levels "E","W","C","N",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert, but is this any help?

```
fac1 <- factor(dat, levels = 
               c("East","West","Central","North","South","None of the above"))
summary(fac1)
```